# how to fetch mint address list from creator (without metaplex)?

Tags: metaplex, nfts

Can I fetch the data mint address from a creator? I need to know what mint addresses have been generated from the creator address.

Can I use the native way without the functions from the Metaplex library (like `metaplex.nfts().findAllByCreator()`)?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this for sure. You can search the findAllByCreator inside the JS Metaplex Repo for the implementation for `findAllByCreator`  or if you want to look at the rust implementation that you can check [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/snapshot.html)